# Smoothness of a polytope

Tags: geometry, polytopes

This might a bit a too general question to ask but I cannot get my head around this definition I found. A polytope $P\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is smooth at the vertex if the set $ \{ (w_1-p),(w_2-p),...,(w_n-p)\}$ can be extended to a basis for $\mathbb{Z}^n$. 
Where do the $w_i$ come from? I understand that they are some vectors by which the set of points should form a base but no word whether the $w_i$ are arbitrary or not. If anyone could give me an explanation or better a concise definition I would be most thankful.

Comment: I would guess that $p$ is the vertex and the $w_i$ are the vertices adjacent to $p$.

Comment: That does make sense.

Comment: $p$ is indeed the vertex but the $w_i$ are not necessarily the vertices adjacent to $p$. They are the first lattice point along each edge incident to $p$. (Being smooth is a property of the cone spanned by the rays along the edges incident to $p$).